# Looking for a word which means "relating to the order in which things are written down or expressed"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word (which may not exist!). It means something like "relating to the order in which things are written down or expressed"; not, however, the the order in a dictionary (that would be "lexicographical") but rather the order in normal writing.

So, if the word was "freddographical" I could talk about English and French being freddographically different because in English one says "blue car" but in French it is "auto bleu". Equally, in the UK we write a date 30/04/2011 but in the US they write 04/30/2011; I would call that a freddographical difference.

Comment: -1 So French and English would be freddo different just because have a noun+adjective in different positions? That will make all languages different. And you compare an entire language with a dictionary...

Comment: In a given context, yes, *freddovariant* (sounds nice, already!). The entire language may not be the subject of the discussion.

Comment: Do you mean _syntax_? That is, the syntax of adjectives is different in French and English?

Comment: Something that encompasses the order in which words appear in a sentence, phrase, *and* conventions like date formatting? *Syntax*, as @Mitch suggested, seems to cover the concept, which is otherwise too narrowly specific to be of much use.

Answer (score 2):

I think the word you are looking for is "respectively."

Comment: I don't think that, *"English and French are respectively different because in English one says 'blue car' but in French it is 'auto bleu'"* makes much sense.

Answer (score 1):

***Ordinal***

In the absence of any specific qualifier such as lexical or chronological, it would probably be just *ordinal* I guess.

Comment: To clarify further, in normal usage, one might describe two jackets as "a green padded jacket" and "a blue padded jacket".

Comment: To clarify further, in normal usage, one might describe two jackets as "a green padded jacket" and "a blue padded jacket". However in a catalogue the descriptions might be "Jacket, Padded, Green" and Jacket, Padded, Blue", so that similar items came together in alphabetical order. The terms mean the same thing, but are clearly not the same. I am looking for a word which encapsulates the difference. (BTW, I am looking for a single word or short phrase as I will have to use it many times in a single document. Such is my useless life!)

Answer (score 1):

You might get away with "precedence" or "priority", though of course neither refers to this specific case.

"Subsequence" or "posteriority" refer to something that follows something else, with "precedence", "antecedence" or "anteriority" working in the other direction.

Are you allowed to coin a term yourself, if you can't find one?  Could languages be *ordoverborically* different?  :-)

Have a look at the [WP Word Order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_order) page for some hints at how this gets expressed by others.

Answer (score 1):

The word is *syntactically*, from:

> [***syntax***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/syntax) : 1. (Linguistics) the branch of linguistics that deals with the grammatical arrangement of words and morphemes in the sentences of a language or of languages in general

Your sentence becomes:

> English and French are *syntactically* different because in English one says "blue car" but in French it is "auto bleu".

Answer (score 0):

In this context, I think the phrase you are looking for is "word order". I'd agree with Kris that "ordinal" would apply in a more general sense, as in, "having to do with order".

Answer (score 0):

The best terms would be *typology* or *morphology*, or derivations (such as *typological*).

Linguistic typology is a field of linguistics that studies and classifies languages according to their structural features.  Morphological typology is a way of classifying the languages of the world according to their common morphological structures, and on the basis of how those languages form words by combining morphemes.

"English and French are typologically different because in English one says "blue car" but in French it is "auto bleu". Equally, in the UK we write a date 30/04/2011 but in the US they write 04/30/2011; I would call that a typological difference."

Answer (score -1):

chronological order is what you're looking for